# How can i increment the of receipt number in pdf after printout of each pdf page using php?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I need to display receipt number by incrementing after printout of each pdf,I am using fpdf for creating receipt,I want to count receipt number for first page 1,for second page 2 and so on.

Can i use session for this?

Any help is appreciated.

Here's my code for pdf:

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST['register']))
    {
        $calender=$_POST['datum1'];
        $time=$_POST['timepicker_6'];
        $respected=$_POST['first_name'];
        $month=$_POST['second_name'];
        $year=$_POST['third_name'];
        $fees=$_POST['fourth_name'];
        $amount=$_POST['fifth_name'];
    require("fpdf/fpdf.php");

    $pdf=new FPDF();
    $pdf->Addpage();
    // Logo
    $pdf->Image('33990.jpg',10,2,30);
    $pdf->SetFont("Arial","B",20);
    $pdf->cell(0,10,"Madirasheri Mahal Jamath ",0,1,'C');
    $pdf->SetFont("Arial","B",18);
    $pdf->cell(0,10,"P.O Thrikanapuram-679573,register number:529/98 ",0,1,'C');

    $pdf->SetFont("Arial","B",18);
    $pdf->Cell(0,10,"Receipt number:",0,0,'C');

    $pdf->SetFont("Arial","B",18);
    $pdf->cell(0,10,"Date:{$calender} ",0,1,'R');  


    $pdf->cell(0,10,"Time:{$time}",0,1,'R');


    $pdf->cell(0,30,"We have received sum of Rs  {$fees},for the month of ",0,1);

    $pdf->cell(0,-15,"{$month},{$year} From Mr/Mrs {$respected}.",0,1);

    $pdf->cell(0,60,"Amount :{$amount} ",0,1);
    $pdf->cell(0,20,"Secretory: ........... ",0,1,'R');

    $pdf->output();
    }
?>
```

I am using fpdf: http://www.fpdf.org

Answer (score 0):

FPDF comes with a built-in function called [`PageNo`](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/pageno.htm) that should accomplish what it is you need.

```
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Receipt number: ".$pdf->PageNo(),0,0,'C');
```